# ReferenceError: document is not defined issue in SSR Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

Can any one help me Server side rendering(SSR), If i remove style-loader fro webpack getting issue with CSS code.

> webpack:///./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?:93
>   var style = document.createElement('style');
>                 ^
>
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>       at insertStyleElement (webpack:///./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?:93:15)
>       at addStyle (webpack:///./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?:208:13)
>       at modulesToDom (webpack:///./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?:81:18)
>       at module.exports (webpack:///./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js?:239:25)
>       at eval (webpack:///./src/App.css?:15:14)
>       at Object../src/App.css (C:\reactjs\ssr-demo\server-build\index.js:1:20922)
>       at a (C:\reactjs\ssr-demo\server-build\index.js:1:172)
>       at eval (webpack:///./src/App.js?:4:66)
>       at Module../src/App.js (C:\reactjs\ssr-demo\server-build\index.js:1:21877)
>       at a (C:\reactjs\ssr-demo\server-build\index.js:1:172)

Comment: Hey! did you find any workaround?

Comment: I was facing the same problem, until I realized I was importing the resulting bundle.js twice. Once manually in <script > tag and the second was done by webpack. Once I deleted the hard coded <script src="./dist/bundle.js"> the error disappeared,

Comment: To add to what @Ademi said, you many have other dependencies in the `index.html` that are being included more than once. I realized that I forgot to remove some of the dependencies in the script tags after installing them through `npm`.